# How to find files older than 60 minutes only in current directory

Tags: shell, unix, find, unix-timestamp

The following command it finding all the files which are older than 60 minutes but in sub directories also.

```
find . -type f -mmin +60 -print
```

How can we restrict it find files only in given directory?

I have archive folders in sub direcotries which have older files that is causing problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-maxdepth 1` argument to `find` to limit results to the current directory.

So your full command would be `find . -type f -mmin +60 -maxdepth 1 -print`

Comment: As with any `option` in `find`, `-maxdepth 1` should come before `actions` and `tests` since `find` will flip it on when it parses the arguments, and will print you an angry warning otherwise. So, should be re-written `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +60 -print`

Answer (score 0):

find ./your-directory -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mmin +10 -type f -delete

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.